# jQuery - Bind action to parent form, determine what child triggered the bind event

Tags: jquery, bind

I have a form that has multiple input fields. I'm applying a `bind()` to this form as so:

```
$("#form-id").bind('keyup change', function(e) {
   //Run some other code
   alert('here');
});
```

I would like to determine the ID of which form field triggered the bind event to fire. I've tried working with the [Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) sent on the function, however the information doesn't seem to reside there. For example, `e.relatedTarget` is null.

Is is possible to determine what child element of the form triggered the bind event to be triggered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the event [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3aevent.target):

```
$("#form-id").bind('keyup change', function(e) {
    var targetId = e.target.id;
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/9r47C/).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it. I don't know how I let this slip past me.

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/event.target/ -- `event.target` should be what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
$('#form-id input').bind('keyup change'), function(e) {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess it had to do with the fact that this is different to what the OP wants. It won't, for example, bind the event to `textarea` elements, only `input` elements.

Comment: Fair point, but it was the suggestion of an idea, not a complete solution.  There's no indication what sort of elements the OP is using in the form.  Downvotes are supposed to be for unuseful answers.

Comment: Your original answer was unuseful. The original answer you provided would only return the ID of the parent form, thus the downvote. You have since edited your answer in to something that could work theoretically, therefore I'll remove the downvote if you edit the answer and unlock it.

Comment: Wow you saw it in a space of 5 seconds from the moment I clicked Post to the moment I edited it to fix that.  What do you mean by unlocking it?

Comment: yet another downvote on a useful answer, without comment!  Do ppl not understand what the downvote is for?

Comment: I'm sorry Jeremy, I refreshed the page and saw what I saw. My advice would to not be so hasty in responding to a question unless you are 100% sure your answer is correct or you have tested it. I still will remove my downvote, but you need to edit your answer for me to be able to do that as my vote is locked in. Just edit your answer and add a space or something so it's different, and I'll remove mine.

Comment: thanks.  It's not a big deal, but it gets me when I think it's undeserved.